# Why apache restart after run for loop

Tags: php, apache

With php 8.0 and Apache 2.4. I have a small code. Ex:

```
<?php
    for($i=0;$i<10000;$i++){

    }
```

I run it with php command and it ok. But when I host my web with apache 2.4, it always restart apache after run this script.

Comment: Nothing else in the loop? Iterating 10000 times empty loop shouldn't have any impact for server's stability. I'd suggest updating/reinstalling it first and/or bringing factory settings if your confs were modified.

Comment: What is your max_execution_time in php.ini file ?

Comment: this could also be caused by the memory limit as in cli mode it is usually set to a higher value than in apache mode. but as stated by @biesior an empty loop should not cause any issue even with thousand of iterations. you should check the logs to see if there is any information on the restart reason

Comment: Nothing in body, and only 10000 loop. Stranger, It only error in apache, work perfect in console

Comment: Definitely weird, 10k empty iterations is nothing. Googling suggest updating servers Apache and/or PHP. I'd start from it.

Comment: Have you checked the Apache and PHP error logs?

Comment: in PHP 8.0.2, this bug was fix :D